Bi-directional HTTP1 full duplex streaming on Android
I have an http1 API that I have written (in Golang) code ex here that I have gotten to work perfectly on iOS code ex here
But I cannot seem how to figure out how to implement it on Android.
The API is atypical in that instead of one server/response pair, any number of them can happen. It is so I can upload pieces of a db, get confirmation, and continue. Similarly data can come down from the website to client. When the iOS client connects I can see the connection gets upgraded, etc... and everything works as expected.
First I tried to implement this using okHTTP web sockets classes. But this does not work because web sockets are considered to be "GET" and the API is "POST". Testing with changing the API to "GET" just to see what happens resulted in the ws library complaining about missing upgrade and connection headers, so I don't believe that's the answer.
Looking into okHTTP further, they have an "isDuplex" method I can override, but the docs plainly state that this only works on http2.
Looking at URLConnection classes and such, they claim to only support one request/body pair per call and will terminate after that, so seems like they won't work.
Any experience with this?

"The API is atypical in that instead of one server/response pair, any number of them can happen." -- what do you think is atypical about that?  Maybe it's atypical if you're talking about pipelining, but that's still covered by the HTTP specifications.  Maybe not so much by any given API.

Are you asking this: Java based HTTP client which supports pipelining?  That Q&A is pretty dated, but it shows that such clients have been around for some time, including before HTTP 2.0 was introduced.

I just meant that if you look most places, they assume that the http protocol limits it to query/response configurations. But in this case, there are multiple chunks of consumable data sent, along with multiple responses sent down in one single call and they are both streamed/chunked transfer (the actual payloads are JSONL lines)

My point is that you will have more success finding information that helps you if you discover and use the correct terminology in your queries.  Even now, I only think you are talking about HTTP pipelining.  I'm still not sure.

Oh I see, and agree. I’m trying to use all the terminology I have available right now which seems to mainly be described as full duplex.
The golang api (shown in the code sample uses that terminology) but the iOS api (i linked an example of that too) seems to only mention streamed uploading.

Pipelining does sound like it might it! But I'm not finding much on a cursory search so far
